Right alt working as left alt. I want it to work as right alt
I seem to be wanting a different thing from the whole world. I want my Right Alt to work as: Right Alt / Alt Gr.
I'm running KDE kubuntu 22.04.
Keyboard is set to generic | generic 104-key pc and the layout is English (US, euro on 5). When I enable Key to choose the 3rd level for Left Alt then any Alt + 5 returns €. Which is more like how I want it but just mapping 3rd level to any alt will break my keyboard shortcuts such as Ctrl + Alt + E (dolphin)
showkey shows me that both sides are mapped to Alt instead of Alt and Alt Gr
keycode  56 press
keycode  56 release
keycode  56 press
keycode  56 release

(me pressing Left Alt and Right Alt consecutively)
Keyboard is a corsair K95 and doesn't have a right alt key labelled Alt Gr, it is just Alt. This might be the problem?

If you do not have an alt gr key how can you expect  to use it?

@David key printing does not necessarily align with the opcodes sent on the wire

The problem was my keyboard config. I'm running ckb-next and apparently I/it configured it to Right Alt -> Left Alt
